# How to configure the EF model when 1-0..1 and 1-many are both necessary

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entity model, `OptionWidget` and `OptionWidgetValue`, `OptionWidget` have many `OptionWidgetValue` like a option list, and sometimes one of those values will be a default one. I know that I can add one more field in `OptionWidgetValue` like `Default` to implement this relationship. But when I try to make another way, that is define the default in `OptionWidget` as the code below, I encounter some errors:

> The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

The following is my model definition:

```
public class OptionWidget : ModelBase
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? DefaultValueId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DefaultValueId")]
    public virtual OptionWidgetValue DefaultValue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OptionWidgetValue> OptionWidgetValues { get; set; }
}


public class OptionWidgetValue : ModelBase
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ValueDependency> Dependencies { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int OptionWidgetId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OptionWidgetId")]
    public virtual OptionWidget OptionWidget { get; set; }
}
```

For the 1-many relationship, I define them with fluent API like this and it works fine. But how should I define the 1-0..1 relationship for the default value. Please help me if you know, thank you very much.

```
 builder.Entity<OptionWidget>()
            .HasMany(e => e.OptionWidgetValues)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.OptionWidgetId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use following Fluent API configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OptionWidget>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.DefaultValue)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

This code makes to side of relation optional but if you want make `OptionWidget` required for `OptionWidgetValue` use this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OptionWidget>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.DefaultValue)
    .WithRequired();
```